# HTML5 ocultar texto y desplegable para seguir leyendo

Tags: html5

No encuentro solución en Google.
¿Se puede ocultar texto y mostrarlo en puro y solo con HTML5? Probe con `<detais><sumary>bla bla bla</sumary></details>` y nada.
En principio saber si se puede, gracias.

Comment: No se puede, para ello tienes que hacer uso de CSS y/o de Javascript. Lo único que puedes hacer es que el texto esté oculto siempre, pero el usuario no podría ejecutar una acción para poder verlo.

Comment: Vale gracias, quería hacerlo en html puro pero veo que no, que o CSS o java etc, ok me sirvió de mucho la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Si estoy entendiendo bien tu pregunta , quieres un botón que oculte texto y al seleccionarlo te lo muestre cierto? Si es así, puedes hacer esto.

**Clase CSS**

```
.spoiler {
    display: block;
    margin: 7px 0px;
}

.spoiler-content {
    background-color: #222;
}

.spoiler div:first-child {
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #39382e;
    color: rgb(247, 247, 247);

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;


    text-align: center;

    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

}

.spoiler div:first-child:hover {
    color: #AAA;
}

.spoiler div:last-child {
    display: none;

    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;

    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

**Clase Javascript**

```
function LMSpoiler() {
    /*
     * CONFIGURARTION
    */

  this.contentTag = "#post"; //id for element which contains spoiler tags (usually main container or something like this)
  this.customShowText = "Mostrar contenido oculto"; //text to show in top of spoilers
  this.customSpoilerClass = "spoiler"; //class used for style spoilers
  this.spoilerTime = 350; //time take to open or close the spoiler

    /*
     * END CONFIGURATION
     */

  this.spoilerParser = function() {
    var content = $(this.contentTag).html();
    var insideText = "";
    var completeSpoiler = "";
    var spoiler = "";
    var spoilerIndex = 0;
    var endPosition = 0;
    var lastPosition = 0;

    try {

      while(content.indexOf("[spoiler]", lastPosition) != -1) { //if there is a tag to convert to spoiler

        lastPosition = content.indexOf("[spoiler]", lastPosition); //takes the position of start tag of spoiler
        endPosition = content.indexOf("[/spoiler]", lastPosition); //takes the position of end tag of spoiler

        insideText = content.substr(lastPosition + 9, endPosition - (lastPosition + 9)); //text which is inside spoiler tags
        completeSpoiler = content.substr(lastPosition, (endPosition + 10) - lastPosition); //all content including spoiler tags

        spoiler = '<div class="' + this.customSpoilerClass + '"><div class="show-button" data-show="spoiler' + spoilerIndex + 
        '" onclick="spoiler(this, ' + this.spoilerTime + ');">' + this.customShowText + '</div><div id="spoiler' + 
        spoilerIndex + '" class="spoiler-content">' + insideText + '</div></div>';

        content = content.replace(completeSpoiler, spoiler); //replace all content with a spoiler

        $(this.contentTag).html(content); //and attach it to content

        insideText = "";
        completeSpoiler = "";
        spoiler = "";

        lastPosition ++;
        spoilerIndex ++;
      }

    } catch(e) {}
  };
}

function spoiler (element, time) {
  var id = $(element).data("show");
  $("#" + id).slideToggle(time);
}
```

**Etiqueta HTML**

```
<div class="spoiler">
<div class="show-button" data-show="spoiler0" onclick="spoiler(this, 350);">Mostrar contenido oculto</div><div id="spoiler0" class="spoiler-content" style="display: block;"><p></p>

<div class="language-java highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code><span class="nc">Podemos</span> <span class="n">usar</span> <span class="o">[</span><span class="n">spoiler</span><span class="o">]</span> <span class="n">y</span> <span class="o">[/</span><span class="n">spoiler</span><span class="o">]</span> <span class="n">para</span> <span class="n">ocultar</span> <span class="n">contenido</span>
</code></pre></div></div>

<p></p></div></div>
```

Comment: Gracias pero quería solo html